# how to align an image in UISlider?

Tags: objective-c, swipe, uislider

I change the swipe of a UISlider button for a picture. the problem is that was out of place, how can I solve this?

link img -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IMOm.png

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    zoomValue = [[defaults objectForKey:@"music.zoom.value"] floatValue];
    self.slider.value = zoomValue;

    [self.slider setThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn-tamanho-fonte"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subclass UISlider and override `thumbRectForBounds:trackRect:value:`.